Get boolean expression from hierarchical Pandas DataFrame
The dataframe is given as :
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        "parent_id": [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4],
        "value": [a>2, b<4, d>5, e<3, h>1, i>10, f>3, g>2],
    }
)

I need  get that string expression:
"or(and (a > 2, 
     or(d > 5, 
        and (e<3,
             or (f > 3, 
                 g > 2)
            )  
       )
    ),

    and(b < 4,
        or(h > 1,
           i > 10)
       )
  )"

I.e.all children should be as parameters of "OR" function , and parent and it's  children should be as parameters of "AND"  function

How is it different from your previous question?

@mozway, i need get string representation of expression , not result of boolean expression

In the first code snippet what is a, b etc?

Given the excellent answers you received here, and the obvious similarities to your current Q, please share your own attempt to solve this. See also research effort.

IIUC, you can use a recursive function like in your previous question:
children = df.groupby('parent_id')['id'].agg(list).to_dict()
values = dict(zip(df['id'], df['value']))

def fold(c):
    if isinstance(c, list):
        return 'or(%s)' % ','.join(map(fold, c))
    if c in children:
        return f'and({values.get(c)},{fold(children.get(c))})'
    return values.get(c)

out = fold(children[0]) # root

Output:
or(and(a>2,or(d>5,and(e<3,or(f>3,g>2)))),and(b<4,or(h>1,i>10)))

Used input:
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        'parent_id': [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4],
        'value': ['a>2', 'b<4', 'd>5', 'e<3', 'h>1', 'i>10', 'f>3', 'g>2'],
    }
)


Many thanks, @mozway !
